# How to find the number of characters in the user input

Tags: python, variables

I'm creating a sort of quiz game in Python and one of the questions is 'type a word that has 5 letters in them'.

Basically, what I want is for the user to type anything that has 5 letters or characters in it, and then python checks if it has 5 letters and if it is correct, it sends them to the next question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your game, i assume you have some while loop that keeps things rolling.

Do this:

```
word = input("Give me a 5 letter word: ")
```

The line above will ask the user for the 5 letter word and their input will be stored in the variable word. Then check

```
if len(word) != 5:
    print "that's not 5 letters..."
```

Answer (score 1):

```
answer = raw_input("What is a five letter word? ")

if len(answer) == 5:
    print "Correct!"
else:
    print "Wrong, that has", len(answer), "letters!"
```

If you are using Python 3 you would need to replace `raw_input` with `input` and put parentheses around the print expressions (because print becomes a function).

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.

```
if len(word) is 5
```

**EDIT**
Apparently this is bad. I did not know at the time of posting.
Anyway for those who are unaware and curios, here is a little experiment

```
>>> a = "hello"
>>> len(a) is 5
True
>>> len(a) is 4
False
>>> len(a) is 5.0
False
>>> len(a) == 5
True
>>> len(a) == 4
False
>>> len(a) == 5.0
True
```

**EDIT again**
Based on a comment by interjay, I further did an experiment.

```
>>> for i in range(1000):
...     a = 'x'*i
...     if len(a) is not i:
...             print(i)
...             break
... 
257
```

If someone could explain why it works up to 256, I'd love to add it here

**EDIT Once more**
This probably explains the behavior. I am quoting interjay from the comments.

> It's an optimization in CPython:
>   Objects for the integers in the range
>   -1 to 256 are preallocated, and each time one of these values is
>   encountered, it is given the same
>   object. For other integers, a new
>   object is created each time. Of
>   course, this is an implementation
>   detail and can change between Python
>   versions.

Comment: the `is` keyword is used for checking the identity of an object. It's better to use `==` for this.

Comment: I dont understand your problem about conventions. Code works, and I wish people like you should get off self righteous ...

Comment: This has nothing to do about being self righteous. You are abusing the fact that under the hood, python uses the same objects for each integer. But if they decide to change this property for some reason, your code breaks. Using code because 'it works' is never a good idea because it can cause all sorts of problems in the future.

Comment: On the other hand, I understand what you meant. Sorry.

Comment: Your edit is still wrong. For example, Try: `a = 'x'*1000; print (len(a) is 1000)` and you'll get False on current CPython versions.

Comment: @interjay, thanks for the clarification!, I noticed that this works only up to 256.

Comment: Is it because each short integer (but not larger integers) has its own objects ? So when you do len("hello") and 5, they are referencing the same object ?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. It's an optimization in CPython: Objects for the integers in the range -1 to 256 are preallocated, and each time one of these values is encountered, it is given the same object. For other integers, a new object is created each time. Of course, this is an implementation detail and can change between Python versions.

Comment: This is completely tangential to the OP's problem. Read the FAQ about the difference between `==` and `is`